# Нужна ли запятая после "но"?

Tags: пунктуация

Но прежде чем начинать пиар-кампанию, обязательно сделайте...

Очень нужен обоснованный ответ. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:  «Но прежде чем начинать пиар-кампанию, обязательно сделайте…» 
В данном случае  присоединительный союз НО тесно связан с  подчинительным союзом ПРЕЖДЕ ЧЕМ, пауза между ними  отсутствует и запятая не ставится, чему дополнительно способствует нераспространенность придаточного предложения.

Для справок

1. СПП может начинаться с присоединительных союзов И, А, НО, ОДНАКО, после которых следует подчинительный союз.
2. После присоединительных союзов И, А запятая обычно не ставится и пауза не делается:   И если бы Марийка не портила настроение, всё было бы хорошо. А когда взошло солнце, пред нами открылся вид на снеговую вершину.
3. Присоединительный союз ОДНАКО относится к главному предложению, произносится с паузой и выделяется запятой:   Однако, хотя уже совсем стемнело, огни на улицах  не зажигались.
4. Для присоединительного союза НО возможны оба варианта, авторский выбор: Но, если даже противнику удавалось отбить атакующих, пехота снова бросалась в атаку. Но как мы ни старались, нам это не удалось.

Comment: Я думала, запятыми выделяется придаточное, а не союз.

Comment: Наверное, следует сказать: присоединительный союз отделяется запятой, при этом  "придаточное предложение выделяется запятыми".

Comment: Бедные наши дети и внуки. В правилах надо исключить двоечтение. Что значит "обычно, допускается и пр?". Это лишний повод снизить оценку. Вот приставка " не" пишется всегда отдельно от глагола и всё, без вопросов. Проще надо быть и учебники понятнее создавать.

Answer (score 0):

Небольшое дополнение. "Прежде чем" - не только подчинительный, но и составной союз, который может интонационно распадаться. Наиболее вероятен вариант: "Но прежде чем начинать пиар-кампанию, обязательно сделайте..." Однако возможны и еще 2 авторских: "Но, прежде чем начинать пиар-кампанию, обязательно сделайте..."; "Но прежде, чем начинать пиар-кампанию, обязательно сделайте..."